# Is there a way to keep the program running while waiting for input?

Tags: c, linux, animation, input, console

We have an assignment to create a game in C. We can't use any external headers, and it should run on console.

I thought it would be cool to have animations going on. We already have a walking character and everything (printing matrix, updating, clearing screen, reprinting...), but it would be nice to have things such as running water, for example. To do that, I'd need a way to keep the program running while waiting for an input. As it currently is, the animations would stop as the user is prompted for an input (and he'll constantly be asked for directions), so it wouldn't work.

I'm wondering if there'd be a way to keep the animation running while the input prompt is still going, maybe having a timeout for the input function and re-prompting every frame until the user starts typing. We're familiar with C, but not with any of the obscure functions and headers that could be used to work around this problem.

How can I keep the program running while waiting for input?

Comment: You could use [select()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) to check if there is user input and do something else if not

Comment: All of this is platform-dependent and cannot be done with standard C. Yet your post is very vague in details of *what* you can in fact use.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm not familiar with that function, but I'll do some research around it. Cheers.

Comment: Multithreading is often the easiest way to implement things like this.

Comment: On Windows with VC there is the non-standard `_kbhit()` which is non-blocking, follow that with `_getch()` also `#include <conio.h>`

Comment: But depending on their definition of "bread&butter" headers, multithreading might not be an option @Barmar

Comment: @FelixG C11 threads.

Comment: @JL2210 good point, didn't think about those since i'm still mostly working with C99

Comment: @FelixG But as pointed out earlier, this can't be done with standard C. So if he's allowed to use POSIX libraries, threading may be easier than select/epoll.

Comment: There are many way to do this. You can use threads. Simple way just check check  kbhit() with time Interval while(kbhit()){ interval(10) }

Comment: You need to tell us on which platform the program is supposd to run. The answer greatly depends on this

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for the help, guys. I've got a lot of learning to do now haha. It's supposed to run on Linux, though I'm coding everything on windows (I dont mind getting a Linux VM if it helps though).

Comment: @Azeew Take a look at pthreads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is just to change stdin over to non blocking.  This is done (on Linux and others) by using the `fcntl()` function to change the `F_SETFL` option on stdin.

That will make `fgetc()` (or any other read) no longer block returning right away.  If there wasn't any thing to read (no input) it will return an error.  If there is something it will return that character.

Here is the call you need to make to change stdin to non-blocking.

`fcntl(0, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);`

The first argument is the file handle.  We pass in 0 which is stdin.  The next argument is the option we want to change (in this case F_SETFL), and the 3rd argument is what to change it to (FNDELAY is non-blocking mode).

Here is a simple example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void SetupIO(void);
void ShutDownIO(void);

int main(void)
{
    long count;
    char c;

    SetupIO();

    count=0;
    for(;;)
    {
        printf("Counting %d\r",count);
        count++;

        c=fgetc(stdin);
        if(c=='q')
            break;
    }

    ShutDownIO();

    return 0;
}

void SetupIO(void)
{
    fcntl(0, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);
}

void ShutDownIO(void)
{
    fcntl(0, F_SETFL, 0);
}
```

This is great.  It no longer blocks, but it still echos the characters being typed and you need to press enter before you will get back any input from `fgetc()`.

If we want to make it more game like we need to tell the terminal to stop messing with our input.  We need to switch the terminal into RAW mode.

The following example turn the terminal to RAW mode and changes stdin to non-blocking.

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void SetupIO(void);
void ShutDownIO(void);

struct termios orig_termios;

int main(void)
{
    long count;
    char c;

    SetupIO();

    count=0;
    for(;;)
    {
        printf("Counting %d\r",count);
        count++;

        c=fgetc(stdin);
        if(c=='q')
            break;
    }

    ShutDownIO();

    return 0;
}

void SetupIO(void)
{
    struct termios new_termios;

    /* take two copies - one for now, one for later */
    tcgetattr(0, &orig_termios);
    memcpy(&new_termios, &orig_termios, sizeof(new_termios));

    /* register cleanup handler, and set the new terminal mode */
    atexit(ShutDownIO);

    cfmakeraw(&new_termios);

    new_termios.c_iflag|=INLCR; // CR=NL
    new_termios.c_lflag|=ISIG;  // We still want Ctrl-C

    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new_termios);

    /* Non-blocking */
    fcntl(0, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);
}

void ShutDownIO(void)
{
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &orig_termios);
    fcntl(0, F_SETFL, 0);
}
```

The downside to this is that if you Ctrl-C or your program crashes it will leave your terminal in a messed up state that is not easy to get back out of.  You can help with this by adding an `atexit()` and/or signal handling.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [select](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) to monitor a file or a group of file descriptors until they have input available. Depending on the structure of your program you could also use asynchronous input where a callback is called when I/O is signaled as ready for a given file descriptor.

The rough snippet below shows the necessary methodology to allow for the callback `action_handler` to be called when input becomes available on the target file description, which emittes SIGIO.  This allows for the input to be processed when it arrives, if it arrives. Using a socket (lets assume UDP) you would have something similar to the following.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
...
create and bind socket
...

/** Set sigaction to use sigaction callback and not handler */
act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO; // Enables sigaction instead of handler
act.sa_sigaction = action_handler; // Callback function

/** Set mask to ignore all signals except SIGIO during execution of handler */
sigfillset(&act.sa_mask); // Mask all
sigdelset(&act.sa_mask, SIGIO); // Clear SIGIO from mask

/** Set callback for SIGIO */
sigaction(SIGIO, &act, NULL)

/** Set socket io signals to async and make sure SIGIO is sent to current
* process when a TCP connection is made on the socket
* */
file_status = fcntl(socket_fd, F_GETFL); // Get current status
file_status |= O_ASYNC | O_NONBLOCK;
fcntl(socket_fd, F_SETFL, file_status); // Set modified status flags
fcntl(socket_fd, F_SETSIG, SIGIO); // Produce a SIGIO signal when i/o is possible 
fcntl(socket_fd, F_SETOWN, getpid()); // Make sure SIGIO signal is sent to current process
```